# List all Pages in a folder in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp

I have 3 folders in View Folder. I want to add first folder's Pages to Flipview.
I don't know how to list all pages. I tried:

```
List<Page> samplePages = new List<Page>();
samplePages.Add(MonajatPage);
```

But it throws an error:

> Error: MonajatPage is a 'type', which is not valid in the given
>   context.

`MonajatPage` is a Page in the first folder

Comment: samplePages.Add(new MonajatPage()); ?

Comment: I need all pages in that folder.

Comment: For the compiler, there is no such thing as Folder. Folders are just for human developers to organize the source code. In other words, only you know how many pages are there in the View folder, so you have to add them to the list one by one.